# SOAP UI basic authentication in java

Tags: java, soapui, soap-client, java-client, google-http-client

This is my Code:

public class JavaSoapUi {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String requestUrl = "myurl";
    URLConnection connection =new URL(requestUrl).openConnection();
    System.out.println( "orignal url: " + connection.getURL() );
    connection.connect();
    System.out.println( "connected url: " + connection.getURL() );     
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestUrl);       
    String username = "user";
    String password = "pass";
    String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary((username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    httpPost.addHeader("AUTHORIZATION", "Basic " + encoded);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);       
    System.out.println("Response" + response.getStatusLine().toString());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();           
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("ResponseString" + responseString);      
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);

}
```

And I am getting output Error :HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

If I used the username and password in the SOAP UI By using the Basic Authentication I can then get the output. But when I am using the same username and password in the Java code I am getting the error.

Any one help me.

Comment: seems you are missing the Content-Type header. Try adding another header: Content-Type: application/xml

Comment: I added the Content-Type header. I am getting the Same error. httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

Answer (score 0):

Your `Authoritzation` http-header looks good to me due you added the header like is defined in [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.2). Furthermore if the problem was with your `Authoritzation` then your call must receive an `Error HTTP 401 Unauthorized` instead you're receiving `Error HTTP 301 - Moved permanently` so probably the error is with your `url`. Check the `location` `http-header` of your `301` error response to see the correct `url` for your service.

**EDIT BASED ON OP COMMENT**

As I said you check the `location` header from `301` error response, and seems that `url` is an `https://`, if you change the `url`, now you're receiving `Error: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` this is due your client has to trust in a server certificate, to do so, download the server certificate from your `url` and load it in the trust store of the JRE where you're executing your client with the follow command (the correct way is to add the `certificate authority` of your server certificate, however to perform a test load directly server certificate it's enough).

`keytool -import -alias somealias -file serverCertificate.cer -keystore JRE_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`

Note that [`keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) is inside java distribution in `JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool`, and default password for `JRE_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` trust store is `changeit`.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I checked the location in the http - header. Location starts from "https: //". When I used the http's in my url I got this "Error: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". Did I want to get the ssl certificate or any further ways for this problem.

Comment: Hi @Rajeshkannan, so the problem was with your `url`, if your url is an `https://` your client have to trust in a server certificate. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can we get the any duplicate ssl certificate @albciff

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment, What do you mean?

Comment: How can I download the  server certificate from my url?

Comment: you can download it for example using the browser, for example with chrome connect to your url at `https`, then click on the padlock at left of your address bar, select the `connection` tab on the popup an click on `certificate information`, now you certificate is show in a new window which has a `detail` tab with a `copy to file` button.

Comment: @Rajeshkannan this finally helps you?

Comment: Getting the Same problem:(